# How to simplify "multiple click counter" Javascript functions into one Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter, simplify

I have multiple buttons and multiple JS functions that show different counter for different buttons. How can I simplify/condense my multiple JS functions into one function that connects each button to its counter?

Here is the workable example for two buttons, two counters and two JS functions. Would you please advise how to simplify/condense it? Many thanks.

TWO JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS and STYLE

```
<!-- JS and Style in head -->
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script>

function clickCounter1() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount1) {
      localStorage.clickcount1 = Number(localStorage.clickcount1)+1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount1 = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount1 + " time(s).";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
</script>
<script>
function clickCounter2() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount2) {
      localStorage.clickcount2 = Number(localStorage.clickcount2)+1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount2 = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount2 + " time(s).";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
</script>
<style>
.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {background-color: #4CAF50;} /* Green */
.button2 {background-color: #008CBA;} /* Blue */
</style>
</head>
<!-- End of Head -->
```

TWO HTML BUTTONS：

```
<p><button class="button button1" onclick="clickCounter1()" type="button" background-color="black" color="white">Click it - Button1 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style="font-size:14px;color:white;"></i></button></p>
<div id="result1"></div>

<p><button class="button Button2" onclick="clickCounter2()" type="button" background-color="black" color="white">Click it - button2 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style="font-size:14px;color:white;"></i></button></p>
<div id="result2"></div>

<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the `clickCounter` function into one.

here changing the related property of `Storage` object depend upon the index of `buttons` node-list.

```
<p>
    <button class="button button1" type="button" background-color="black" color="white">Click
        it - Button1 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style="font-size:14px;color:white;"></i></button>
</p>
<div class="result"></div>

<p>
    <button class="button Button2" type="button" background-color="black" color="white">Click
        it - button2 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style="font-size:14px;color:white;"></i></button>
</p>
<div class="result"></div>
```

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const results = document.querySelectorAll('.result');

function clickCounter(button, index) {
    const property = "clickcount" + index + 1;
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage[property]) {
            console.log(localStorage)
            localStorage[property] = Number(localStorage[property]) + 1;
        } else {
            localStorage[property] = 1;
        }
        results[index].innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage[property] + " time(s).";
    } else {
        results[index].innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}

buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        clickCounter(button, index)
    })
})
```

Comment: I have tried it as below ~ it can not show the result：

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEVMUWOWWT2D

Comment: found that the `script` tag is in the wrong place. put it at the before of `</body>` tag and it works fine.

Comment: Got it! I have moved the Script from <head> ... </head> tags into <body>...</body> tags. It's work. Would you please advise what's the key difference for those two places? I don't know how to justify the right place.

Comment: various tags in HTML are loaded in what order they appear on the structure. the script tag is loading before the body tag. if you `console.log(results)`  you will get empty `nodeList` because they are not loaded. that's why all script tags must be before the end of the body tag. which means all HTML element is loaded on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to keep your code structure,
so I used `function parameter` and localStorage methods `getItem, setItem`

// html

```
<p>
      <button
        class="button button1"
        onclick="clickCounter(1)"
        type="button"
        background-color="black"
        color="white"
      >
        Click it - Button1
        <i
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
          style="font-size: 14px; color: white;"
        >
        </i>
      </button>
    </p>
    <div id="result1"></div>

    <p>
      <button
        class="button Button2"
        onclick="clickCounter(2)"
        type="button"
        background-color="black"
        color="white"
      >
        Click it - button2
        <i
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
          style="font-size: 14px; color: white;"
        >
        </i>
      </button>
    </p>
    <div id="result2"></div>

    <p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
    <p>
      Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will
      continue to count (is not reset).
    </p>
```

// JS

```
function clickCounter(num) {
  let counterIndex = `clickcount${num}`;
  console.log(counterIndex, localStorage);
  if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem(`clickcount${num}`)) {
      localStorage.setItem(
        `clickcount${num}`,
        Number(localStorage.getItem(`clickcount${num}`)) + 1
      );
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem(`clickcount${num}`, 1);
    }
    document.getElementById(`result${num}`).innerHTML =
      "You have clicked the button " +
      localStorage.getItem(`clickcount${num}`) +
      " time(s).";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(`result${num}`).innerHTML =
      "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it as bwlow ~ it's workable and could duplicate a new Button3:

[link] (https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEVMY0PRRS9V)

Comment: above is like: +1 and could be accumulated after we close the browser. 

Here is the like and dislike counters, its JS and HTML as below. It can add-on and remove, but can not be accumlated after close the browser.  How to extend your JS to its original JS, maybe you have more advise:

The JS, CSS and HTML practice result as below: [W3SCHOOL] (https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEVOR8BFNNVV)

Would you please advise more.